# Why when upgrading to Node.js 16.13.0 (with its nmp 8) I can't stop sass error output?

Tags: npm, sass, gulp, node-sass, gulp-sass

As a result of upgrading to Node.js 16.13.0 with its nmp 8 I ran into a problem with Sass. I had to update gulp-sass to version 5.0.0, additionally install sass@1.43.4 and fix in gulpfile.js the sass require as `sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'))`.

So Sass got finally up and running with Node.js 16 and its nmp 8, but I ran into the problem of Breaking Change: Slash as Division.
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/slash-div
I get Deprecation Warnings like:

```
Deprecation Warning: Using / for division is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div(20em, 16)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
12 │ $fa-fw-width: (20em / 16);
   │ ^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules\@fortawesome\fontawesome-free\scss\_variables.scss 12:25 @import
    node_modules\@fortawesome\fontawesome-free\scss\fontawesome.scss 5:9 @import
    assets\src\style\_variables.scss 6:9 @import
    assets\src\style\main.scss 27:9 root stylesheet
```

Everything works, but the error output in the npm console annoys me a bit. How to fix it?

In my gulpfile.js, I use gulp-plumber@1.2.1. It prevents pipe breaking caused by errors from all gulp plugins.

```
plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
```

I have the function to build css:

```
// style build
function css_build () {
    return gulp.src(path.src.style) // pass the string or the array of values pointed above if we want to pass several ones
        // .pipe(cached('css_building'))
        .pipe(plumber()) // gulp plugins bug tracking
        .pipe(gulpif(devMode, sourcemaps.init())) // initialize source maps
        .pipe(sass()) // scss -> css
        .pipe(autoprefixer({ // add vendor prefixes to CSS
            overrideBrowserslist:  ['last 2 versions'], // last two versions recommended by plugin developers
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css)) // deploy temporary css
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' })) // add prefixes to the deployed file
        .pipe(cleanCSS({level: {1: {specialComments: 0}}})) // minify CSS and disable even special comments
        .pipe(gulpif(devMode, sourcemaps.write('./')))  // write source maps
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css)) // deploy final css
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true })); // browser-sync reload
}
```

And as a result of executing this task that kind of errors occur mentioned above.
So the question is how can I stop outputing these errors?
I'm not really going to rewrite third-party css libraries myself for it and use div() instead of / there :)

Comment: It appears not, see https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/2822#issuecomment-482914373.  But what us this?: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/34051#issuecomment-846486905

Answer (score 0):

There is a super solution for solving this Deprecation Warning problem.

First uninstall nodejs from your projec & after use below command,

```
nmp i --legacy-peer-deps
```

That will be solve your problem.